# iPad 4 webcam hacking

Tags: ipad

I received an email from my email address dedicated to Facebook blackmailing me. Saying that he had hacked my webcam and has videos for me. He wants 1000$ in the form of bit coins. What's your advice in such a situation? Thanks

Comment: Delete the mail, it‘s just a scam.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how come he is using one of my email addresses?

Comment: Email addresses can be easily faked.